# Использование protected-сеттеров в public-методе.

Tags: ооп, php

Собственно сабж, можно ли?
Например, так:

```
<?php

class someClass{

private $a = 0;

protected function getA ()
{
    return $this->a;
}

protected function setA ( $a )
{
    $this->a = $a;
}

public function someFunc(){
    if( $this->getA == 0 ){
        $this->setA( 1 );
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Естественно можно. Внутри класса, вы можете использовать любые его методы. Суть `private/protected/public` в том, как свойства или методы будут доступны из вне. Например: `public` доступны везде, protected доступны только потомкам класса, а `private` только внутри класса где они объявлены.